# This case falls into usage, not grammar?

Tags: grammar, usage

**punch1 /pʌntʃ/ ●●● S3 verb [transitive]

1 HIT to hit someone or something hard with your fist**
If I don't hit someone on my fist but I hit someone far from my fist with the other means (for example, with a gun), isn't it against grammar but is it just against usage?
I quoted the definition to restrict the meaning of 'punch.'

Answer (score 2):

Neither. There are a lot more meanings of punch than you quote so your question starts from a false premise.

I can put a mark onto a sword with a metal punch.

I can drink a fruit punch.

I can use a gun to punch a hole in the bad man.

I think you might have a meaningful question to ask but what you did ask doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: Note that the middle example is not a different sense of "punch" but an etymologically unrelated word, that happens to have the same spelling and sound.  A fruit punch comes from Hindi, meaning "5" (as they originally were a mix of five ingredients)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116756/discussion-on-answer-by-jwpfox-this-case-falls-into-usage-not-grammar).

Answer (score 2):

A sentence can be grammatical but nonsensical or meaningless; perhaps the most famous example is "[Colorless green ideas sleep furiously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)", made up by Noam Chomsky. It is grammatically well-formed: it obeys all the rules of English grammar (for instance the verb "sleep" agrees with the subject "ideas"), but what does it mean? Nothing as far as either I or Chomsky can tell.

Similarly a sentence like "He punched me with his hair" or "He punched me over the telephone" might be considered nonsensical, or interpreted in a metaphorical way. Punch typically refers to hitting with a fist, although it can be used for other similar motions, but it would require something hard that makes a firm impact (e.g. a hole punch, a leather punch, etc). It would be correct to say that the word "punch" is misused.